# iOS: unreleased dispatch queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, release, grand-central-dispatch

So for downloading and displaying an image I used to do something like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("bgQ", 0), ^{
    // download image
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // display iamge
    });
});
```

But I realized that this way I'm not releasing the dispatch queue.
So the question is, **do we need to declare the queue separately so that we can release it later** or can we release the queue somehow in the first example?

Do we need to do it like this?:

```
dispatch_queue_t bgQ = dispatch_queue_create("bgQ", 0);

dispatch_async(bgQ, ^{
    // download image
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // display iamge
    });
});

dispatch_release(bgQ);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // download image
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //display image
    }
    }
```

or for download image try this  [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that we should not user dispatch_get_global_queue, for whatever reason

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already know of the async imageview implementations out there, my question is only aimed at the principle of using dispatcH_async and handling dispatch_queues

Comment: Never mind I remembered that it wasn't get_global_queue that was advised against but get_current_queue. Thanks for the answer!